# Read/Write between windows c++ application and Ipad using libusbmuxd library

Tags: c++, ios

current use [libusbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd) to work around pc and iPad. libusbmuxd is very helpful to get device (iPhone/iPad) information when connects to Mac app through USB.

I want more, I want to read/write data (a file like document, image, video, ...) from pc to iPhone and vice versa but I can't get any document or tutorial on the Internet guiding how to do it.

Can anyone help me

Comment: There should be guides online if you search long enough. Alternatively look for open source projects who have already done this and get the source code of them. There you have some examples.

Comment: Could you please send me some links.i search on web but i couldn't find one  ?